# use golang in docker container in multi-stage build

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I want to use multi-stage build and I want that at the end I will have Golang inside the running container.
When I run the container  and do go version I get error “unknown go”

```
# build stage
FROM golang:1.11.2-alpine3.8 AS builder-env



ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
ENV GOOS=linux


ADD https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/download/v0.5.0/dep-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/dep
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/dep

RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github/mtp/myproj
WORKDIR  $GOPATH/src/github/mtp/myproj


COPY Gopkg.toml Gopkg.lock ./


RUN dep ensure --vendor-only

COPY . ./



RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix nocgo -o /myproj .


FROM alpine:latest
RUN mkdir /data

COPY --from=builder-env myproj ./
```

I can do something like this to make it work, but is it a good options ?

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN mkdir /data
RUN update-ca-certificates && \
    apk add go 

COPY --from=builder-env myproj ./
```

Comment: Since you want Golang inside the container, why do you use multi-stage?

Comment: @tgogos - this is part of my docker and I want at then end to have mininal docker image with my go application and golang iside

Comment: An idea would be to use `FROM golang:1.11.2-alpine3.8` again at the second step (instead of `FROM alpine:latest`) but I don't know if this will work. Let's see if anyone else proposes something different.

Comment: The great thing about 2 stage builds is that you can just have a scratch container with the compiled binary in it. You don't need to run a full-blown alpine image with that binary, I'd recommend you either use `FROM scratch` or a really bare bones image with ca-certs and all: `gcr.io/distroless/base`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `go` executable to run a compiled program, just the resulting binary.  If you add in the missing CMD line to your Dockerfile

```
CMD ["./myproj"]
```

I'd expect it would work fine.

Comment: It's recommended to use `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` in this case

Comment: I prefer CMD for two reasons: it’s common enough to write an ENTRYPOINT that sets up environment variables and then runs the CMD; and it’s common to want to `docker run sh`.  Both of those get harder if you set the bundled application as ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: The whole point of a 2 stage docker build is to remove cruft from a container to run in production, that's why I said it's recommended _in this case_

Comment: @DavidMaze - Thanks, this is I know :) I can use also the scrath image and it will work with multi stage build. I mean I need that the mulitstage build also include golang ... but the multistage will be from alpine .